# SpringBoot build Error: "org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found from resources"

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I have a new *SpringBoot* project that I'm using *gradle* as the build manager and *Eclipse IDE*.

I want to use *hibernate* and the configurations from `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, but I'm getting:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
```

I store this file in `resources` folder, also I tried put it into `META-INF` folder.

project structure:

[image]

`HibernateUtil.java`:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static  SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();


 private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
   {
      try
      {
         if (sessionFactory == null)
         {
             sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
         }
         return sessionFactory;
      } catch (Throwable ex)
      {
         System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
      }
 }

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    // Close caches and connection pools
    getSessionFactory().close();
}
```

}

Comment: You don't need to configure hibernate, spring boot does it for you, please have a look at the spring JPA doc https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: I second @Saravana, the only configuration you should be touching will be adding the dependency in the pom. Gone are the days of tweaking config.xml files. Let Spring handle this for you :-)

Comment: If I am correct understand, Spring Data JPA is alternative for Hibernate, yes?

Comment: JPA is a specification and hibernate is one of its implementations

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the files in the resources directory, you need to use the classloder to get the file.

In static method

```
HibernateUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResource("hibernate.cfg.xml").getFile();
```

non static method

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("hibernate.cfg.xml").getFile();
```

and if the resource resides in any of the sub directories of `resources`, prefix the folder path while getting the resource

Example to get the resource in META-INF directory

```
getResource("META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

But spring boot auto configures, just by adding dependencies in `pom.xml` and providing JPA related properties in `application.properties`

Answer (score 0):

If your application is a *web-service* then you should put `hibernate.cfg.xml` in `WEB-INF` folder.

If your application is *client-service* then you should put your `hibernate.cfg.xml` in `src` package.